# example on how to automate google spread sheet using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, automation, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

**This one is just a knowledge share example.** 
This is my example for automation for google spread sheet via gmail using selenium webdriver

```
 package com.google;

    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;


    public class testgoogle {

        static WebDriver driver;
        static WebElement element;

        public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{

            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("http://www.gmail.com");
            //sign in
            driver.findElement(By.linkText("Sign in")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("username");
            driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("password");
            driver.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
            //sleep till page is loaded --necessary
            Thread.sleep(15000);


            String parentHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); 

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='gbwa']/div[1]/a")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("gb25")).click();
            //Perform the click operation that opens new window
            System.out.println("this one should be the gmail" + driver.getCurrentUrl());

                     // switching the window to google drive
            for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
                driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); 

            }

            System.out.println("this one should be the google drive" + driver.getCurrentUrl());
            element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='navpane']/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]"));
            new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).click().perform();

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=':1t.cmi']")).click();

                    // switching it to google sheet window from google drive window
            String parent2Handle = driver.getWindowHandle(); 
            for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
                driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }

            System.out.println("this one should be the spread sheet" + driver.getCurrentUrl());
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/div/div")).sendKeys("hello this is first field");

            driver.close();
                     // accept the leave window alert.
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            alert.accept();
                     //closes the google drive window
            driver.switchTo().window(parent2Handle);
            driver.close();
                    // closes the gmail window
            driver.switchTo().window(parentHandle);
            driver.close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: So?What is your problem exactly?

Comment: i saw many questions on this specific topic. so thought to share it here once.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. But if you want to answer your own question, please do it in QA style, i.e. put an answer in the answer. Also XPath  like `//table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div/div/div` or `/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[1]` are horrible, please use something better.

Comment: Now, if you can turn that into a standard "page object" that would be impressive.  the way that it currently is, its not very usable by others.  If you want to just share, post a GitHub Gist and then embed the code in your blog.

Comment: One can access google spreadsheet using Google Sheets api v4 which is much easier and don’t requires much code. Google Sheets API use the OAuth 2.0 protocol for authentication and authorization
Check out below website for example on how to integrate spreadsheet for selenium tests using Google Sheets latest API.
http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/read-data-from-google-spreadsheet-using-api

Comment: @DevRaj Thanks for sharing.  This example was shared by me 4 yrs back when I was way too junior. :)

Comment: @ArpanBuch Cool. I thought it would help someone who is looking something like this.