# Google SpreadSheet Read and Write

Tags: java, google-sheets

I had coded to take input from excel sheet and write to excel sheet PASS or Fail.
I am using Apache POI to get this done.
Here is sample code for same :

```
for (int row=1 ;row<=5;row++)
{    
//This will second cell value in first row.
System.out.println(sheet.getRow(row).getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
//This will set value pass on 4th cell of first row.
sheet.getRow(row).createCell(4).setCellValue("Pass");
}
```

Now I am want to attain same using google spreadsheet , I am able to read and write from sheet , but not able to apply this as I had done using APACHE POI ,

Just for quick ref :
**To Read Data from spread Sheet**

```
ValueRange response = service.spreadsheets().values()
                .get(spreadsheetId, range)
                .execute();
        List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
        if (values == null || values.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No data found.");
        } else {
            for (List row : values) {
                // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
                System.out.println(row.get(0));
            }

        }
```

**And To Write :**

```
List<List<Object>> values1 = Arrays.asList(
                Arrays.asList("PASS")
                // Additional rows ...
                );
        ValueRange body = new ValueRange()
                .setValues(values1);
        UpdateValuesResponse result =
                service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId, range, body)
                .setValueInputOption("RAW")
                .execute();
        System.out.printf("%d cells updated.", result.getUpdatedCells());
```

Can some one please suggest how to attain same working as I had done using Apache POI

Thanks

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325619/example-on-how-to-automate-google-spread-sheet-using-selenium-webdriver) could help?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion , but this is not I am looking for.